# How to check if paypal ipn response (for protection hack)?

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

How to check if paypal ipn response (for protection hack) ?

now i use this code for check

```
if (!isset($_POST["txn_id"]) && !isset($_POST["txn_type"]))
    {  //user press paypal button//  }
else
    { // paypal ipn response and insert data to mysql//   }
```

but i think this code not secure , because if user create fake `$_POST[txn_id]` and `$_POST[txn_type]` in paypal button form my code will go to insert data to mysql.

Please help me for create code that can protection hack .

thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [IPN solution PayPal provides](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php).  It handles all of this for you.  I would just build into that.

If you look at that script, though, you'll see how it parses out the data that was POSTed to it, then regenerates an NVP string to POST right back to PayPal using CURL.  The response to that request would contain either VERIFIED or INVALID, and based on that you can process the IPN accordingly.

Again, that template does it all for you, so you could simply start at line 105, where it has the if/then logic for whether or not the IPN is verified.